# How to pass props with React/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have a website that uses React, React-redux, now I am converting it into Typescript, but I can't. I have this:

Login.tsx

```
....
import ValidationErrors from 'components/ValidationErrors'
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'store/hooks';

function Login() {
    
    ...
    ...
    const errors = useAppSelector(state =>state.error) 

    return (        
        <div className="login">                     
           ....
            { errors.errors.length &&                                             
                <ValidationErrors errors={errors} />                    
            }
         ...
         </div>
      )
}
```

components/ValidationErrors.tsx

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Errors from 'interfaces/Errors';
    
    function ValidationErrors( {errors}: Errors ) {            
        return (                
            <div>
                <div className="font-medium text-red-600">{errors.message}</div>                
                <ul className="mt-3 list-disc list-inside text-sm text-red-600">
                    {Object.keys(errors.errors).map(function (key, index) {                        
                        return <li key={index}>{errors.errors[key]}</li>;
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>        
        );
    }

export default ValidationErrors
```

interfaces/Errors.ts

```
export default interface Errors {
    message:string | null,
    errors: {
        [key:string]:string[]        
    }
}
```

This is the json format that backend send when there is an error:

> {
> "message":"The given data was invalid.",
> "errors": {
> "email": ["These credentials do not match our records."]
> } }

I get 2 typescript errors:

> {Object.keys(errors.errors).map(function (key, index) {
> return {errors.errors[**key**]}; })}
>
> (parameter) key: string Element implicitly has an 'any' type because
> index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)

and here:

> <ValidationErrors **errors**={errors} />
>
> (property) Errors.errors: {
> [key: string]: string[]; } Type 'Errors' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string[]; }'.   Index signature for type 'string' is
> missing in type 'Errors'.ts(2322) Errors.ts(3, 5): The expected type
> comes from property 'errors' which is declared here on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & Errors'

This is the error reducer: store/reducers/errorReducer.ts

```
import Errors from 'interfaces/Errors'
import {Action, ActionType} from 'store/types'

const initialState: Errors = {
    message: null,
    errors: {
        '':['']
    }   
}

export const errorReducer = (state : Errors = initialState, action: Action): Errors =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case ActionType.SET_ERROR:          
            return {
                message: action.payload.message,
                errors: action.payload.errors
            }                   
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

and this my global reducer: store/reducers/index.ts

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
...
...
import {errorReducer} from './errorReducer'


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    .....
    error: errorReducer
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export default rootReducer;
```

And this is my store: store/store.ts

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './reducers'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: afaik `function ValidationErrors( {errors}: Errors ) {` should be `function ValidationErrors( {errors}: { errors: Errors}) {` (you applied the Errors interface to `props` instead of `props.errors`, I'll also recommend to name the interface `IErrors`)

Comment: You are destructuring errors object from the error response so you need to use another type, or you do not destructure and say ( errorResponse: Errors ) {
const { errors } = errorResponse
}

Comment: Thanks dudes, now it is working, but you mentioned that I applied the Errors interface to props, that seems to be true because it is working now, but I thought that I  should only destructure the props, not the interface, that's why I did this  {errors}, it is still confusing

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways to fix this,

1. Don't destructure the function's parameters and refer to Errors interface

   ```
   function ValidationErrors(errors: Errors) {

   }
   ```
2. Provide information about each value that you will get on destructuring parameters.

   ```
   function ValidationErrors({ message, errors }: { message: string | null, 
   errors: { [key: string]: string[] } }) {

   }
   ```